# How to change the display orientation with a keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, display-settings

In windows I can change screen orientation by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>[Arrow]</kbd>. Is there such a shortcut in Ubuntu or how to define one?

Comment: The title is not a question

Comment: Is not the screen orientation changing in Windows you described a feature of a particular graphic driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution (it's not really ubuntu style) is using xrandr

```
xrandr -q
```

You may want to do the following to rotate the screen/turn screen on off:

```
xrandr --output LCD -o [normal,inverted,left,right]
xrandr --output LCD --off
xrandr --output LCD --auto
```

Finally

xbindkeys is a program that binds commands to keys or key combinations on the keyboard. In xbindkeysrc, after creating a script with the previous command,

```
 "rotate.sh" 
   control+shift + q
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the right solution is simply

```
xrandr  -o [left | right | normal etc ]
```

command in the terminal does the job.

And if you want to create a shortcut go to Settings > Devices > Keyboard > Shortcuts > + (add shortcut)

paste the appropriate command. For example,

```
xrandr -o left
```

and choose a key combination that suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Update on Ubuntu / POP!_OS 20.04 (if you don't use any other external screen):

```bsh
# rotate left
xrandr --output $(xrandr |grep eDP|cut -d" " -f1) --rotate left

# rotate right
xrandr --output $(xrandr |grep eDP|cut -d" " -f1) --rotate right

# rotate normal
xrandr --output $(xrandr |grep eDP|cut -d" " -f1) --rotate normal

# rotate inverted
xrandr --output $(xrandr |grep eDP|cut -d" " -f1) --rotate inverted
```